# Check whether a condition holds within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, find

I have a list of lists (converted to an array using NumPy) as follows:

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 4,  3,  1],
       [ 5,  2,  1],
       [ 8,  4,  1],
       [ 9,  4,  1],
       [12,  3,  1],
       [13,  2,  1],
       [14,  3,  2],
       [15,  1,  1]])
```

I would like to get a Boolean variable indicating whether there is any row in the above array that its first and last columns are equal to r1 and r2, respectively. Note that r1 and r2 are constant numbers. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What is `r1` and `r2`? Are those constant numbers? rows?

Comment: Thank you. Constant numbers.

Comment: `condition = any(row[0] == r1 and row[2] == r2 for row in array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your conditions inside `np.any`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 4,  3,  1],
       [ 5,  2,  1],
       [ 8,  4,  1],
       [ 9,  4,  1],
       [12,  3,  1],
       [13,  2,  1],
       [14,  3,  2],
       [15,  1,  1]])

np.any((a[:,0] == 15) & (a[:,2] == 1))
# True

np.any((a[:,0] == 14) & (a[:,2] == 1))
# False
```